# Equality of Segments in a Corner with Two Tangent Inscribed Circles

Tags: triangles, circles, angle

#### The problem

> Two circles are inscribed in the corner. Points $A$ and $B$ are points of contact of the first circle with the sides of the angle, points $A_{1}$ and $B_{1}$ are points of contact of the second circle with the sides of the angle. The segment $AB_{1}$ intersects these circles at points $C$ and $C_{1}$. Prove that $AC = B_{1}C_{1}$

#### The figure

**Excuse me for the quality*

[image]

##### So far of what might be helpful for the ultimate proof I've managed to prove:

1. $ABB_{1}A_{1}$ is an isosceles trapezium.
2. $ABB_{1} \sim B_{1}C_{1}A_{1} \sim BCB_{1}$.

I've tried to make a case for proving that $ACA_{1} = B_{1}C_{1}A_{1}$, but at first I need to prove somehow that two of their angles are equal. The problem itself is of the *"First similarity property of triangles"* matter and I've tried different ways to approach the problem, but I haven't proven what's initially required.

##### I will gladly appreciate any help, guidance, and suggestions!

Comment: Hint: $\text{AC}_1*\text{AB}_1=\left(\text{AA}_1\right){}^2$

Comment: @Lozenges, ohh, I see. Thank you!